# Meteor js - Console shows 'Undefined' even if returning result

Tags: javascript, meteor, undefined

I have the following Helpers for a simple posts archive:

```
Template.archive.helpers({
    itens: function () {
        return Itens.find();
    }
});

//singleExcerpt is the single item on archive loop
Template.singleExcerpt.helpers({
    shortExcerpt: function() {
        var a =  this.text.slice(0,120);
        return a+'...';
    }
})
```

And on archive page, it lists all posts and its `shortExcerpt` of 120 chars, but still it returns a Undefined on console:

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
```

Does anyone knows what might be the problem here?

Comment: So it actually works but throws at a point? Do you maybe have a post that doesn't have a `shortExcerpt` field? Maybe try/catch it and check which post throws.

Comment: What subscriptions do you have on the `Itens` collection?

Comment: This was the problem, @Kyll, thanks for the insight! A simple `if (this.text) {` did the trick. Should you post it as an answer so I award you as correct? I am quite new on how stack overflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after discussion in the question comments, it happens to be an issue of data existence - some of the collection documents simply don't have a `shortExcerpt` field.

To solve this, either enforce the presence of this field with [a package such as `aldeed:collection2`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2), make some data validation yourself...
You also have the option to take it into account in your template:

```
Template.singleExcerpt.helpers({
    shortExcerpt: function() {
        var a = '';

        if(typeof this.text !== 'undefined') {
            a =  this.text.slice(0,120);
        }

        return a + '...';
    }
});
```

However, I would advise making sure absolutely all your documents have the very same structure. In that case, it would mean that the `shortExcerpt` must always be defined, even if only containing an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

use RegisterHelper 
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper

```
Template.registerHelper('shortExcerpt', function(text, limit) {
    return text.substring(0, limit) + (text.length > limit  ? '...' : '');
});


Template.archive.helpers({
    itens: function () {
        return Itens.find();
    }        
});

<template name="archive">
    {{# each itens }} 
        {{ shortExcerpt text 150}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

use all templates

```
{{ shortExcerpt 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit.' 80 }}

--> "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adi..."
```

Comment: I will test your suggestion latter, @yaşar-İÇlİ, as it brings some good validations for showing or not the '...', but I did solve the `undefined` using a `if (this.text) {` just to check if text do exists. As, of couse, we cannot slice something that dont exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Template.archive.helpers({
    shortExcerpt: function(text) {

        if(text.length>120){
          var a =  text.slice(0,120);
          return a+'...';
        }

        return text;
    }
})

<template name="archive">
    {{# each itens }} 
        {{ shortExcerpt text }}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```